# XMPP connection in android using smack

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, smack, asmack

I am getting this error  while running the code. I am using smack 3.1.0 and smackx3.1.0 alon with android extension of smack (smack-android-4.1.0-alpha6)

```
09-01 15:28:37.430: E/NativeCrypto(9558): ssl=0x670ec948 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x6790a938 arg=0x0
09-01 15:28:37.431: E/NativeCrypto(9558): ssl=0x670ec948 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=DHE_RSA
09-01 15:28:38.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9558): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #6
09-01 15:28:38.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9558): Process: com.example.xmppkoderootapp, PID: 9558
09-01 15:28:38.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9558): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-01 15:28:38.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9558):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
09-01 15:28:38.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9558):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
09-01 15:28:38.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9558):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
09-01 15:28:38.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9558):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
09-01 15:28:38.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9558):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
09-01 15:28:38.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9558):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
09-01 15:28:38.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9558):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
09-01 15:28:38.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9558):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
09-01 15:28:38.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9558): Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: org/jivesoftware/smack/sasl/SASLMechanism
09-01 15:28:38.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9558):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
09-01 15:28:38.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9558):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
09-01 15:28:38.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9558):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticate(SASLAuthentication.java:304)
09-01 15:28:38.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9558):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:395)
09-01 15:28:38.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9558):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:349)
09-01 15:28:38.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9558):     at com.example.xmppkoderootapp.SettingsDialog$LongOperation.doInBackground(SettingsDialog.java:69)
09-01 15:28:38.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9558):     at com.example.xmppkoderootapp.SettingsDialog$LongOperation.doInBackground(SettingsDialog.java:1)
09-01 15:28:38.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9558):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
09-01 15:28:38.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9558):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
09-01 15:28:38.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9558):     ... 4 more
```

Here is my code

**SettingsDialog.java**

```
package com.example.xmppkoderootapp;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence;

/**
 * Gather the xmpp settings and create an XMPPConnection
 */
public class SettingsDialog extends Dialog implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {
    private XMPPClient xmppClient;

    public SettingsDialog(XMPPClient xmppClient) {
        super(xmppClient);
        this.xmppClient = xmppClient;
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);
        getWindow().setFlags(4, 4);
        setTitle("XMPP Settings");
        Button ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok);
        ok.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        String host = getText(R.id.host);
        String port = getText(R.id.port);
        String service = getText(R.id.service);
        String username = getText(R.id.userid);
        String password = getText(R.id.password);
        new LongOperation().execute("im.koderoot.net","5222","im.koderoot.net","xxxx@im.koderoot.net","xxxx");

        dismiss();
    }

    private String getText(int id) {
        EditText widget = (EditText) this.findViewById(id);
        return widget.getText().toString();
    }

    private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // Create a connection
             // Create a connection
            ConnectionConfiguration connConfig =
                    new ConnectionConfiguration(params[0], Integer.parseInt(params[1]), params[2]);
            XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);

            try {
                connection.connect();
                Log.i("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Connected to " + connection.getHost());
            } catch (XMPPException ex) {
                Log.e("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Failed to connect to " + connection.getHost());
                Log.e("XMPPClient", ex.toString());
                xmppClient.setConnection(null);
            }
            try {
                connection.login(params[3], params[4]);
                Log.i("XMPPClient", "Logged in as " + connection.getUser());

                // Set the status to available
                Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
                connection.sendPacket(presence);
                xmppClient.setConnection(connection);
            } catch (XMPPException ex) {
                Log.e("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Failed to log in as " + params[3]);
                Log.e("XMPPClient", ex.toString());
                    xmppClient.setConnection(null);
            }

            return "Executed";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Log.e("In onpost execute ", "Success");
            // TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
            //txt.setText("Executed"); // txt.setText(result);
            // might want to change "executed" for the returned string passed
            // into onPostExecute() but that is upto you
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {}

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
    }
}
```

**XMPPClient.java**

```
package com.example.xmppkoderootapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.filter.MessageTypeFilter;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.filter.PacketFilter;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Packet;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.util.StringUtils;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class XMPPClient extends Activity {

    private ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList();
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private SettingsDialog mDialog;
    private EditText mRecipient;
    private EditText mSendText;
    private ListView mList;
    private XMPPConnection connection;

    /**
     * Called with the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        Log.i("XMPPClient", "onCreate called");
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mRecipient = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.recipient);
        Log.i("XMPPClient", "mRecipient = " + mRecipient);
        mSendText = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.sendText);
        Log.i("XMPPClient", "mSendText = " + mSendText);
        mList = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listMessages);
        Log.i("XMPPClient", "mList = " + mList);
        setListAdapter();

        // Dialog for getting the xmpp settings
        mDialog = new SettingsDialog(this);

        // Set a listener to show the settings dialog
        Button setup = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.setup);
        setup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        mDialog.show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        // Set a listener to send a chat text message
        Button send = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.send);
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String to = mRecipient.getText().toString();
                String text = mSendText.getText().toString();

                Log.i("XMPPClient", "Sending text [" + text + "] to [" + to + "]");
                Message msg = new Message(to, Message.Type.chat);
                msg.setBody(text);
                connection.sendPacket(msg);
                messages.add(connection.getUser() + ":");
                messages.add(text);
                setListAdapter();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Called by Settings dialog when a connection is establised with the XMPP server
     *
     * @param connection
     */
    public void setConnection
            (XMPPConnection
                    connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
        if (connection != null) {
            // Add a packet listener to get messages sent to us
            PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
            connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
                public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                    Message message = (Message) packet;
                    if (message.getBody() != null) {
                        String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message.getFrom());
                        Log.i("XMPPClient", "Got text [" + message.getBody() + "] from [" + fromName + "]");
                        messages.add(fromName + ":");
                        messages.add(message.getBody());
                        // Add the incoming message to the list view
                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                setListAdapter();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }, filter);
        }
    }

    private void setListAdapter
            () {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.multi_line_list_item,
                messages);
        mList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Hope this isn't too late, the Error refers to SASL verification, and I've noticed you haven't set anything regarding that in your doInBackground(), try the following in your try block (might not be exactly what you need, but it's basic):

```
ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration(server, port);

//... any other stuff you need

//very basic security stuff just to get you going...
config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
XMPPTCPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("DIGEST-MD5", 0);
connection.connect();

//... any other stuff you want

connection.login(user, passw);
```

Hope this helps!